# Metrics data rollups schema design for a big dataset

Tags: database-design, nosql, schema, rethinkdb

In a project I am currently working on, I have a collection of raw metrics, these metrics are about signal tracking as:

Table: metrics

```
{timestamp: 1535875518111, project_id: 1, type: 'A', strength: 100}, 
{timestamp: 1535875528111, project_id: 2, type: 'B', strength: 80}, 
{timestamp: 1535875528101, project_id: 1, type: 'B', strength: 50}
```

As there are literally millions of records for the metrics table per day it seems inefficient to query and aggregate the records for results extraction.

I have read a lot about data rollups per day/week/month but I am still confused about how I can roll my schema. I want to extract data as:

From October to November and for project with id 1, what's the overall hit range and what are the top 10 types?
For type A of project with id 1, how many occurrences have been made and what's the highest range?

My first thought was rolling the data as:

```
{
  day: 21,
  month: 10,
  year: 2018,
  project_id: 1,
  types: {
    'A': {
      hits: 100,
      strengths: {
        '100': 1,
        '200': 2
      }
    },
    'B': {
      hits: 20,
      strengths: {
        '2': 1,
        '5': 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above structure looks OK but, as the range of types is growing, I think it would be hard to query the nested results. Also, I am not quite sure how I should add indexes in order to improve my queries' performance.

I am really seeking for any caveats or tips in order to design a schema about rollups. The database I am currently using is RethinkDB but I think the same principles apply to generic schema design.

Comment: 1/ I don't know what a "rollup" is, and neither does Duckduckgo, apparently - would you mind linking to a clear definition?
2/ Maybe related to 1/, but what are you really after? Tips on how to aggregate data ("rollup" or so it seems)? Tips on how to query/index this "rolled up" kind of document you display?

Comment: Just edited your post, please check the delta when (if!) it's published because I took some guesses about what you meant.